# How to use server sent event for control elements display for this case dom javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

How to use server sent event for control elements display for this case dom javascript ?

I tried to hide element on server sent event using dom but not work, how can i do ?

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.8.3_test_jquery.minjs.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>


<div id="hide_this_id">test</div>
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined")
{
    var source = new EventSource("test2.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data +"<br>";
    };
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "not support";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$loop = "1";

while($loop <= 1)
{   
?>
<script>
    document.getElementById("hide_this_id").style.display = "none";
</script>
<?PHP
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5); // wait for 5 seconds
}
?>
```

Comment: That's two different pages. How do you make a request for test2.php from a first page?